# PHP - Matching only unicode alphanumeric and punctuation symbols

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have this regular expression:

```
'/^[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+(\s+[\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+)*$/u'
```

**Goal**: Match valid (first|last) names (people names) using unicode characters, like "D'Agatti" or "María" or whatever. Some special symbols like hyphens must also be included.

**Issue**: It is also matching NUMBERS.

**Question**: How can I avoid matching numbers? What character classes should I use?

Comment: Your pattern works well for me, perhaps the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, it was somewhere else. It was in DRUPAL. Drupal and it's silent errors raelly SUCK (yes, I knew it after I accepted the answer since I tested the answer elsewhere :s). Actually drupal SUCKS everytime and everywhere. This time it truncated a handler's name (i had an apparently "too-long" handler name even when identifiers length is not a PHP limitation), so my actual handler was never called (and even then no "function does not exist" was triggered!!! had to cast incan magic to see what was happening)

Comment: I sympathize with you, good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way of matching names can be as follows:

`'/^([^\d]*)$/u'`

This matches everything except numbers.

However, as you say it is too broad for names. You can finally run this test on the result you get from your original test to remove the names with numbers.

Comment: It's too broad for names, but I think I could use a subsidiary /\d+/ to check (later) if the (valid, by the prev. regex) name has digits and raise error on that case.

Comment: Accepted the modified answer.

Comment: @sshashank124 could you help me with this as well? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22867392/php-matching-city-street-names-in-php-using-unicode-regex It's similar but for this issue digits are allowed, however digits must consist on it's own term, and not be part of other (non-digit) terms

Comment: found the issue! finally had no issue with unicode, but with DRUPAL not calling a handler because "it's name was too long". Drupal sucks, seriously.