# PHP - Matching city/street names in PHP using unicode regex

Tags: php, regex, unicode

I have this expression:

```
'/^([\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+|\d+)(\s+([\p{L}\p{Mn}\p{Pd}\'\x{2019}]+|\d+))*$/u'
```

It's **goal** is to match names and numbers like "6 de diciembre" or "Mariana de Jesús" (using numbers and unicode characters.

The **issue** is that it also matches typos like: "6de diciembre" [1]. **Mixing numbers and letters in the same word should not be allowed** (no, we have not expression like "6th" in this cases).

Question: **What character classes should I use**? I need digits and these unicode letters, but not mixed, not concatenated.

Notes: I posted a similar question regarding this topic before, but the issue was slightly different and cannot expect the same kind of answer.

[1] I can't believe I MUST clarify this point: **typos should not be matched - unless explicitly said, a regex is to find an expected regular format in a string**

Comment: if your input isn't regular (e.g. randomish/arbitrary), then you're going to have a very difficult time using a regular expression to match that randomness...

Comment: I didn't say it's randomish. I said it was a name, and gave you examples and an explanation: terms are separated by whitespaces, and are only numbers or (unicode letters|punct. symbols|hyphen). Doesn't sound random at all.

Comment: Typos must not be matched, of course. that's what a regex is used for.

Comment: Actually reading the question should lead you to conclude that 1. matched typos are an unexpected issue (I'm saying "issue" and explaining in present simple), 2. Gave examples of what I need to match. 3. Gave a **bold** text explaining what I shouldn't match. 4. Asked for a group of character classes telling that "need digits and these unicode letters, but not mixed, not concatenated".

Answer (score 0):

The expression works well. I had a totally different issue **in which my validation handler was not called**.

After a bit of experimentation I noticed that if I reduce the length of the validation handling function **then the DRUPAL 7 form can use it as a handler, instead of silently discarding it**. Yes, ladies and gentlemen, my handler was named `toyotaec_form_webform_client_form_trabaja_con_nosotros_validate` and assigned as:

```
`$form['#validate'][] = 'toyotaec_form_webform_client_form_trabaja_con_nosotros_validate';`.
```

Slicing the 'con_notros_' part in both sides made it work, and lead me to this conclusion.

.: Drupal has a(n absolutely senseless) limit for those identifiers, while PHP has not.
.: Drupal truncates the input when you assign it.
.: Drupal raises no error upon unexistent function (the truncated name does not exist as a function).

Rantful (but logic) conclusion: For this and many previous issues I conclude that drupal *sucks*.